# Thinkpad BIOS update: USB drive won't boot

Tags: debian, iso, bios, thinkpad

I can't get a bootable USB drive to work when updating firmware for my Thinkpad x260 running debian 10.

The steps that I've taken so far, to no avail, are:

1. Downloaded the latest .iso from Lenovo support.
2. Used genisoimage to extract the bios update:

`sudo genisoimage -o biosUpdate.img r02uj74d.iso`

3. Copied this `.img` file to a usb drive:

`sudo dd if=biosUpdate.img of=/dev/sdb`

4. I then restart, pressing F12 to get to the boot menu, and select the USB drive.

At this point, the screen goes blank for a second or two and I'm returned to the boot menu.

The USB drive shows up as "CDROM" in the devices list.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong that means that I can't boot into the USB drive from the boot menu?

---

**Edit**: for clarity, multiple guides on how to do this advised the above. E.g. https://blog.raveland.org/post/thinkpad_update_bios/

Comment: Did you try with just a `dd` burning of the iso itself?

Comment: I'm using `fwupdmgr` for updating firmware of my X280 with Ubuntu 20.04. No need to fiddle with all these boot settings anymore. [It looks like Lenovo provides updates for the X260 through this tool](https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devices/com.lenovo.ThinkPadR02ET.firmware) as well.

Comment: @MartinKonrad I tried to do this, but the firmware version I had was too old (second hand laptop and had clearly never been updated). There does seem to be support for the x260 if running newer versions of the firmware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to update the firmware using a version of the method in the question.

The difference was that rather than using the debian package `genisoimage` from the repo, I used the perl script that the package is based on (downloaded from [https://userpages.uni-koblenz.de/~krienke/ftp/noarch/geteltorito/geteltorito/](https://userpages.uni-koblenz.de/%7Ekrienke/ftp/noarch/geteltorito/geteltorito/)).

Substituing the `geteltorito` script for `genisoimage` produced a `.img` file which, when flashed to USB as above, worked perfectly.

There might be something amiss with the `genisoimage` package.

This guide details the process using the script: https://makandracards.com/operations/39925-lenovo-laptop-bios-update-with-linux

Answer (score 2):

https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/r02uj74d.iso is already an ISO image, please try to dd it directly to your USB.

If it doesn't work, maybe you need to burn an actual CD/DVD and boot from it. It's a classic ISO image without UEFI.

[BIOS download page](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x260/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI).

---

Alternatively, I've extracted their Windows updater and prepared files to copy to a FAT32 formatted drive. Just [download the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sdMqNCVB58B6B-qycj4zEyR10elUfwBF/view?usp=sharing) and extract its contents to your USB drive. You can then boot from it and update BIOS.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. It almost worked, however, I get the error "invalid capsule file when secureflash is on in rom" when in the updater. 

A quick google leads me here(https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/Cannot-update-X260-BIOS/td-p/3808366) , which says that the EFI updater is outdated in the windows package. 

I've tried mounting the ISO to extract the files, but the image won't mount properly - either the raw ISO or the extracted version with genisoimage

Answer (score 0):

You can make a GRUB menu entry by editing (or creating) the file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and adding the entry below:

```
menuentry "BIOS Update" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    linux16 /boot/memdisk
    initrd16 /boot/bios.img
}
```

You should look for the existing file containing the line `exec tail <some id>` and add the entry below that.

*Notes:*

- `hd0,msdos1` is your main GRUB partition, where your boot files resides.
- The `memdisk` file is a copy from a `syslinux` file with the same name. Copy it under `/boot` directory.
- The `bios.img` file is the output after you use `geteltorito` on your `.iso` image. Copy under `/boot` directory.

After that update your GRUB (`grub-update` command) and reboot your machine. You should see a new GRUB menu entry named *BIOS Update*.

More details: https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/BIOS_Upgrade#Booting_using_GRUB